# FlatList scroll to end w/o knowing items' height

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

My requirement is to display in the view a new item just added to the end of the list rendered by a FlatList.

The problem is when using the `scrollToEnd` method, it only scrolls to the last item that is already rendered in the view (about item #20) but not to the last item in the data array.

From the React Native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltoend):

> May be janky without `getItemLayout` prop.

But my list items have dynamic height according to its content. The items' height can't be calculated, since each item has a different height. so I have no way to implement the `getItemLayout` prop.

Any workaround?

Comment: have you tried `scrollToIndex` with last index?

Comment: `flatList` support `scrollView` props, so i think `onLayout` is what you need

Comment: @JaydeepGalani I've tried scrollToIndex, it does not work either